# How to fix problems regarding connection between Android program and MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, database, database-connection

I am very new to Android and php. I was following a turtorial from a website and made a program that sends and year and receives the info of people in my database who are born after it. However, I am getting these logcat errors:

```
09-23 18:30:04.146: ERROR/log_tag(16030): Error in http connection   java.net.UnknownHostException: www.enjoyen.in
09-23 18:30:04.146: ERROR/log_tag(16030): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 18:30:04.154: ERROR/log_tag(16030): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

I'm not sure how I should fix that

This is my java file:

```
public class PS extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources 

    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;

    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite/sampleDB/HAconnect.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                            ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                            ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                            ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                    );
            }
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

}
}
```

And this is my php file:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

What should I do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to search by "android UnknownHostException". This is emulator problem. To solve it try to restart emulator or recreate avd

Comment: I'm actually using my phone (Motorola Droid). And how do you create avd?

Comment: Avd - android virtual device. For create it launch SDKManager - virtual devices - new - choose options and API level - create.

Comment: Haha, I found my error. I didn't have any permission for INTERNET. Thank you though.